# Error al hacer migraciones en Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

al hacer las migraciones de las tablas, en mi proyecto de **laravel 5.5**. me aparece este error, limpie y configure la cache, pero permanece el error, alguien me ayuda?.

Gracias

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_incr
  ement primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not n
  ull, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null,
  `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character
   set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
  ady exist
```

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta que te han dado?

Answer (score 1):

Proba en el archivo de migration dropear la tabla si ya existe antes de crearla:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //todos los campos que quieras
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```